# The same object 2 time in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I got a problem with my datagrid. When i click on an element my row become selected and my selected style apply.

[image]

but when i scroll, if the element is there again (not duplicate value, item reference are the same), it become in blue, like selected default style.
[image]

Having the same item highlight is not a problem, but i would like to put my selected style (the violet dot in row header). In debug, the rows in blue are not selected (and if they were my style would apply). What is the property for being highlight for the duplicate object.

**Edit**

```
Binding oBindRowSelected = new Binding();
Binding oBindCellSelected = new Binding();
Binding oBindBackGround = new Binding();
Binding oBindBorderBrush = new Binding();
Binding oBindForeGround = new Binding();
oBindRowSelected.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(DataGridRow), 1);
oBindCellSelected.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(DataGridCell), 1);
oBindRowSelected.Path = new PropertyPath(DataGridRow.IsSelectedProperty);
oBindCellSelected.Path = new PropertyPath(DataGridCell.IsSelectedProperty);
oBindBackGround.Path = new PropertyPath(DataGridRow.BackgroundProperty);
oBindBorderBrush.Path = new PropertyPath(DataGridRow.BorderBrushProperty);
oBindForeGround.Path = new PropertyPath(DataGridRow.ForegroundProperty);


DataTrigger oTriggerSelectedImageVisibility = new DataTrigger();
oTriggerSelectedImageVisibility.Binding = oBindRowSelected;
oTriggerSelectedImageVisibility.Value = true;
oTriggerSelectedImageVisibility.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Visible));
DataTrigger oTriggerSelectedCell = new DataTrigger();
oTriggerSelectedCell.Binding = oBindRowSelected;
oTriggerSelectedCell.Value = true;
oTriggerSelectedCell.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty, oBindBackGround));
oTriggerSelectedCell.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BorderBrushProperty, oBindBorderBrush));
oTriggerSelectedCell.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.ForegroundProperty, oBindForeGround));

Style oRowHeaderSelectorStyle = new Style(typeof(Border));
oRowHeaderSelectorStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.CornerRadiusProperty, new CornerRadius(7)));
oRowHeaderSelectorStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.HeightProperty, 15.0));
oRowHeaderSelectorStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.WidthProperty, 15.0));
oRowHeaderSelectorStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.BlueViolet));
oRowHeaderSelectorStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Hidden));
oRowHeaderSelectorStyle.Triggers.Add(oTriggerSelectedImageVisibility);

ControlTemplate oCtlTemplate = new ControlTemplate();
FrameworkElementFactory oBorder = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Border));
oBorder.SetValue(Border.StyleProperty, oRowHeaderSelectorStyle);
oCtlTemplate.VisualTree = oBorder;

Style oRowHeaderStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridRowHeader));
oRowHeaderStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridRowHeader.WidthProperty, 25.0));
oRowHeaderStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridRowHeader.TemplateProperty, oCtlTemplate));

Style oCellStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
oCellStyle.Triggers.Add(oTriggerSelectedCell);

this.RowHeaderStyle = oRowHeaderStyle;
this.CellStyle = oCellStyle;
```

I am working in an extension, so my style is in C# code.

Comment: Show us the style you're applying.

Comment: What type of object is in your data grid?

Comment: datagrid.ItemsSource = List<string>() for test. I have 5 dummy string repeat 12 time. If i select 1 of the five i see 11 blue cells.